# How to pull date/time in french format for wordpress post?

Tags: php, posts, date-time

I am working on a wordpress post in which **I want the date/time in frech format as shown below:**

```
ENGLISH

By FJ
Published April 9, 2019 at 4:05 p.m.
Last updated April 9, 2019 at 4:14 p.m.


FRENCH

Un texte de FJ
Publié le 9 avril 2019 à 16 h 05
Mis à jour le 9 avril 2019 à 16 h 14
```

I have used the following code to pull the date/time in english/french for wordpress post:

```
<strong><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
By
<?php }else{ ?>
Un texte de
<?php  } ?><?php the_author(); ?> </strong><br>
<strong><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
Published
<?php }else{ ?>
Publié le
<?php  }  ?><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
at
<?php }else{ ?>
à
<?php  }  ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> </strong><br>
<strong><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
Last updated
<?php }else{ ?>
Mis à jour le
<?php  } ?><?php the_modified_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
at
<?php }else{ ?>
à
<?php  }  ?> <?php the_modified_time('g:i a'); ?> </strong>
```

The above code **displays the following o/p which is not correct(date and time format) in the case of french**. English is fine but french doesn't seem to work.

```
By FJ
Published April 9, 2019 at 4:05 p.m.
Last updated April 9, 2019 at 4:14 p.m.

Un texte de FJ
Publié le avril 9, 2019 à 4:05
Mis à jour le avril 9, 2019 à 5:14
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter the format of the date/time based on language.  This is done by altering the parameters in the_time function.  See below for change options.  Put the code into the if statement (as an example):

```
<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
    Last updated <?php the_modified_time('F j, Y'); ?>
    at
<?php }else{ ?>
    Mis à jour le <?php the_modified_time('j F Y'); ?>
    à
<?php  } ?>
```

You could make it even simpler by adding the time in the same function rather than calling each 2x.  This will save time and space.

```
<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){ ?>
    Last updated <?php the_modified_time('F j, Y /a/t g:i a'); ?>
    at
<?php }else{ ?>
    Mis à jour le <?php the_modified_time('j F Y /à h /h i a'); ?>
<?php  } ?>
```

I've only shown for modified but you can remove `modified_` above and it will work for the creation date.

Notice for the french I changed `g` to `h` to move to 24 hour time.

See here for more info:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time